# When i extrude a error massage apears

Tags: extrude

Hello i wantet to ask if anybody had this problem before. If i want to extrude anything blender will show me this error message. What can i do to fix this?
[image]

Comment: maybe share your file and describe how it happened? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This should be reported as a bug.